# kustomer API get request for customer by a custom field

Tags: api, crm, kustomer

Is there any way to a get request for customer by a custom field? I want to mark a customer as deleted and then get all customers excluding the ones that have been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the best way to do this is to start by adding a custom boolean field to the customer and then post to `/v1/customers/search`

```
{
    "and": [{
        "customer_custom_deletedBool": {
            "equals": "true"
        }
    }],
    "or": [],
    "queryContext": "customer"
}
```

Which will return all deleted customers.

Or

```
{
    "and": [],
    "or": [{
        "customer_custom_deletedBool": {
            "not_set": true
        }
    }, {
        "customer_custom_deletedBool": {
            "equals": "false"
        }
    }],
    "queryContext": "customer"
}
```

Which will return all customers that do not have the deleted flag set, or have deletedBool set to false.